# Putting a NetScaler infront of Redis master failover

Tags: redis, netscaler

I have a redis-sentinel solution for master failover, I just need to setup a vserver with all the master services in the pool. Only one master can act as the master at a time, the rest are slaves waiting for promotion.

I only see options to load balance with vservers. What I really need is a setting that will send all requests to service1 until it's marked as DOWN by the monitor, then start sending requests to the server sentinel promoted.

Is this possible with the NetScaler, or is load balancing between the services a must?